# EventListener para este javascript

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Tengo el siguiente `javascript`:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var pos = $('#center').position(),
  radiusSat = $('#sat1').width() * 0.5,
  radius = $('#center').width() * 0.5,
  cx = pos.left + radius,
  cy = pos.top + radius,
  x, y, angle = 0,
  angles = [],
  spc = 360 / 5,
  deg2rad = Math.PI / 180,
  i = 0;

for (; i < 5; i++) {
  angles.push(angle);
  angle += spc;
}

/// space out radius
radius += (radiusSat + 10);

loop();

function loop() {

  for (var i = 0; i < angles.length; i++) {

    angle = angles[i];

    x = cx + radius * Math.cos(angle * deg2rad);
    y = cy + radius * Math.sin(angle * deg2rad);

    $('#sat' + i).css({
      left: x - radiusSat,
      top: y - radiusSat
    });

    angles[i] = angles[i] + 1;
    if (angles[i] > 360) angles[i] = 0;
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
});
```

Lo que quiero es insertarle un evento que al hacer click en uno de los circulos pequeños, el movimiento continuo pare y me envie el circulo al medio.

Llevo cuatro dias con esto, y no doy con la solucion, Soy algo noob en javascript asi que agradeceria cualquier ayuda.

P.D:dejo el link del post original de deonde saque el codigo.
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/F8x4p/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que algo así es lo que buscas:

```
var pos = $('#center').position(),
    radiusSat = $('#sat1').width() * 0.5,
    radius = $('#center').width() * 0.5,
    cx = pos.left + radius,
    cy = pos.top + radius,
    x, y, angle = 0, angles = [],
    spc = 360 / 5,
    deg2rad = Math.PI / 180,
    i = 0,
    animation;

for(;i < 5; i++) {
    angles.push(angle);
    angle += spc;
}

/// space out radius
radius += (radiusSat + 10);

loop();

$(".circle").on("click", function() {
    // Esto cancela la animación
    cancelAnimationFrame(animation);

    // Esto centra el círculo clicado
    $(this).css({
        top: '175px',
        left: '175px'
    });
});

function loop() {

    for(var i = 0; i < angles.length; i++) {

        angle = angles[i];

        x = cx + radius * Math.cos(angle * deg2rad);
        y = cy + radius * Math.sin(angle * deg2rad);

        $('#sat' + i).css({left:x - radiusSat, top:y - radiusSat});

       angles[i] = angles[i] + 1;
       if (angles[i] > 360) angles[i] = 0;
    }

    animation = requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
```

La animación se puede cancelar con [cancelAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/cancelAnimationFrame)

Comment: Muchisiiimass gracias,
no es completamente lo que estaba buscando pero desde aqui puedo partiry completarlo.
Muchas gracias, de verdad, estaba que me tiraba de los pelos.

Answer (score 0):

Modificando un poco lo que tienes, se puede hacer así (el mover elegantemente hasta el centro te lo dejo pendiente):

```js
var pos = $('#center').position(),
    radiusSat = $('#sat1').width() * 0.5,
    radius = $('#center').width() * 0.5,
    cx = pos.left + radius,
    cy = pos.top + radius,
    x, y, angle = 0, angles = [],
    spc = 360 / 5,
    deg2rad = Math.PI / 180;
    
let clicked=0;
console.log(pos);
for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) { //let por var, importante!
    angles.push(angle);
    angle += spc;
    $(`#sat${i+1}`).click(function () {
     clicked=i+1;
    });
}

/// space out radius
radius += (radiusSat + 10);


loop();

function loop() {

  for(var i = 0; i < angles.length; i++) {

    angle = angles[i];

    x = cx + radius * Math.cos(angle * deg2rad);
    y = cy + radius * Math.sin(angle * deg2rad);

    $('#sat' + i).css({left:x - radiusSat, top:y - radiusSat});

    angles[i] = angles[i] + 1;
    if (angles[i] > 360) angles[i] = 0;
  }
  if (!clicked) {
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
  } else {
    requestAnimationFrame(moveToCenter);
  }
}

function moveToCenter() {
  let clickedDiv=$(`#sat${clicked}`);
 let position=clickedDiv.position();
  let centerX=position.left+25;
  let centerY=position.top+25;
  if (centerX > cx) {
   centerX-=1;
  } else if (centerX<cx) {
   centerX+=1;
  }
  if (centerY > cy) {
   centerY-=1;
  } else if (centerY<cy) {
   centerY+=1;
  }
  
  if (Math.abs(centerY-cy) > 1 || Math.abs(centerX-cx)>1) {
   clickedDiv.css({left:centerX-25, top:centerY-25})
   requestAnimationFrame(moveToCenter);
  }
  
}
```

```css
div {
    border-radius:50%;
    border:2px solid #000;
    position:fixed;
}
#center {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    left:100px;
    top:100px;
    
}
#sat0, #sat1, #sat2, #sat3, #sat4 {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="center"></div>
<div id="sat0"></div>
<div id="sat1"></div>
<div id="sat2"></div>
<div id="sat3"></div>
<div id="sat4"></div>
```

Comment: Esta esta muy terminado eh, ahora solo me tengo que poner a resetear el movimiento con otro click y modificar un poco la funcion para que esta sea compatible con imagenes.Mes estoy volviendo loco, no tenia mucha idea de jscript, ahora con vuestros ejemplos y despues de 4 dias de lectura lo veo algo mas claro....xDD. Gracias